# what is the purpose of using shift() in fillna() function?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Can anyone explain this code ?

```
for i in range(1,10):
    full_df[f'prev_target_{i}'] = full_df.sort_values(by='ID')

['Segmentation'].fillna(method='bfill').shift(-i).sort_index()
```

Comment: I don't think this code actually works at all. Did you try to run just this snippet of code?

Answer (score 0):

As you maybe able to infer from the documentation, located here, shift will move your columns down a couple of periods, which you can then use fillna() on if you wish. It even has its own fill parameter.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html